# Craft model and populateModels() performance issue?

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, performance

I'm getting a big performance hit on front end requests (+15 seconds) when using a model to store / use data from one of my custom fieldtypes, cp requests for the same data appear unaffected.

The prepValue function:

```
public function prepValue($value)
{
    if( is_array($value) )
    {
        return FruitGrid_BlockModel::populateModels($value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

And the model which is getting populated:

```
class FruitGrid_BlockModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'row' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'col' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'sizex' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'sizey' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'entryid' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'rules' => array(AttributeType::Mixed),
        );
    }

    public function getRuleClasses()
    {
        $string = '';
        if(is_array($this->rules))
        {
            foreach ($this->rules as $rule => $value)
            {
                switch ($rule)
                {
                    case 'fixedHeight':
                        $string .= ' height-'.$value;
                        break;
                    case 'desktopRuleOne':
                        $string .= ' desktop-'.$value;
                        break;
                    case 'tabletRuleOne':
                        $string .= ' tablet-'.$value;
                        break;
                    case 'mobileRuleOne':
                        $string .= ' mobile-'.$value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return trim($string);
    }

    public function getEntry()
    {
        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        $criteria->id = $this->entryid;
        return $criteria->first();
    }
}
```

And pretty standard usage on the front end:

```
{% if entry.customFieldHandle|length %}

    {% for block in entry.customFieldHandle %}

        <h1>{{ block.entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ block.entry.text }}</p>

        ...

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid calling `block.entry` multiple time per block since you only need to do that database query once. Alternatively you can use function memoization to cache the entry like this:

```
class FruitGrid_BlockModel extends BaseModel
{
    private $_entry;

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'row' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'col' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'sizex' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'sizey' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'entryid' => array(AttributeType::Number),
            'rules' => array(AttributeType::Mixed),
        );
    }

    public function getRuleClasses()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function getEntry()
    {
        if(!$this->_entry){
            $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
            $criteria->id = $this->entryid;
            $this->_entry = $criteria->first();
        }

        return $this->_entry;

    }
}
```

This will only get the entry from the database once.

Also recommend renaming the `rules` attribute on the model to something like `blockRules`.

When you loop over the rules to create the ruleClasses string you may be looping over every rule created by the AttributeType declarations in your `defineAttributes` method.

Comment: Ah I see, removing ```{{ block.ruleClasses }}``` improved things a drop, but I was accessing ```{{ block.entry.customField }}``` loads of times, storing / caching the entry and accessing it via this var helped loads. So does it get the entry each time i hit block.entry??

Comment: ah yes, you are doing a db call every time you do `block.entry`. You could cache it in the plugin function or just assign it once per block in the template like so: {% set blockEntry = block.entry %}. This would have been causing the huge slowdown more than my answer.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue, although your suggestion certainly helped speed things up. What do you mean by cache in the function? Set a var that is checked before grabbing the entry and set only if it has not be retrieved?

Comment: Sorry Luke, just saw you answer! Exactly as expected, thanks!!!